# How do I pick files with respect to a particular folder in python?

Tags: python, filepath

I have a specific folder structure laid down by the business which is "/content/2020/May/13-05-2020".
At present I am consuming all files from this location.

But what I would rather want is to pick/consume files based on a daily batch process(as date being mentioned in file path).

To make it simple let us say that in the file path if today's date, May month and 2020 year present then it should process the file using "/content/2020/May/13-05-2020" .

Else it should check for the year , month and date in the same way and proceed accordingly.

Comment: And where did you hit a problem?

Comment: can u share a little bit more detail about your problem?

Comment: You need to provide a [minimum viable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in order for folks to properly assess your issue.

Comment: built a path directly with the date, Then call os.path.exists method to see whether it exist. If yes, you can call os.listdir() method to list files in that folder; if os.path.exists method return false, do other things you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this might be what you're looking for:

```
from datetime import datetime
import os

today = datetime.today()
date = today.date()
month = today.strftime("%B")
year = today.year

path = os.path.join("/content", str(year), str(month), str(date))
print(path)
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this helps:

```
import datetime
import os

date = datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
month = datetime.datetime.today().month
year = datetime.datetime.today().year

mypath = os.path.join("/content", str(year), str(month), str(date))

if not os.path.exists(mypath):
    print("No folder for the current date found!")
else:
    os.chdir(mypath)
```

Comment: there are a few issues here, first, you don't keep an absolute path in `mypath` since you didn't put a `/` in the beginning. second, you use `os.chdir` to the path and then check if it exist, when it should be the other way around.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback :)

Comment: Thanks for all your support.